# Scraping product's colors of an online store using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation, build-automation

So, I am **scraping** an [online store](https://www.michaelkors.global/en_IN/?color=0063) and having trouble in items that have more than one color, as for each color available sizes & price is changing so i need to click on each color and extract the data for it.

My problem is in clicking on each extracted color stored on a list

```
colors_available = []
color_main = soup.find('li', {'class': 'facet-color-options selected'})['title']
colors_available.append(color_main)
color_remain = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'facet-color-options deselected'})
if color_remain:
    for color in color_remain:
        colors_available.append(color['title']) # collecting all available colors
        # hover(color.find('input')['name'])
        # select('COLOR', color)
        click(color['title']) # click on color 
        time.sleep(3)
        print(f'color CLICKED is: {color}') # confirm on color clicked
    print(f"Colors: {colors_available}") # print full str list of available colors
```

Note: also used "Select" & to "Hover" on link then click it with no use giving below error:

```
LookupError
```

hope that it is fully explained and that u can support the soonest as it irritated me for a while

Comment: Could you share the URL?

Comment: https://www.michaelkors.com/knit-puff-sleeve-cropped-sweater/_/R-US_MF06PGXG9V?color=0063

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ not scrapping

Comment: Welcome to SO! In the future, you should try to avoid pasting images if you can fit the text into the question so that people searching can better find your question. Instead of uploading a screenshot, can you paste your Error message as text inside of a markdown code block?

Comment: thanks @barny for the note and edit

Comment: @AkilanManivannan  Noted and will be followed in the future.

Comment: Hope that u all can help me with this problem soon